# Doctrine: How to do a UPDATE with a SELECT MIN subquery?

Tags: select, doctrine, subquery

I have a photos table where users can have multiple photos.

I'm trying to create the following query:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->update('Photo p')
   ->set('p.photo_type', 1)
   ->where('p.user_id = ?', $id)
   ->andWhere('p.date_added = (SELECT MIN(p.date_added) FROM Photo p WHERE p.user_id = ?)', $id)
```

The idea is to set the "photo_type" to 1 for that specific photo of this user that has the minimum date added (earliest photo).

I just can't seem to get the syntax right. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

It seems I'm trying to do something that can't be done, as per the answer to this question ([MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)). This question can be closed.

Comment: Don't you need GROUP BY when using an aggregate function like MIN? Also, you can turn your select table into a join or simply rewrite using either table variables or hash tables

Comment: First try putting GROUP BY date_added just before your WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->update('Photo p')
   ->set('p.photo_type', 1)
   ->where('p.user_id = ?', $id)
   ->orderBy('p.date_added', 'desc')
   ->limit(1);
```

Comment: Yep, this would have worked... should be ORDER BY ASC, though. DESC will start with the max (latest) date.